# C# how can I make a if/else statement with fields instead of types

Tags: c#

I need help, I need to make a Audio button for my screen recorder.  I need to make a if/else statement with fields,

```
private void Audiotext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Audiotext.Text = "Audio: ON";
    EncoderDevice AudioDevices()
    {
        EncoderDevice foundDevice = null;
        Collection<EncoderDevice> audioDevices = EncoderDevices.FindDevices(EncoderDeviceType.Audio);
        try
        {
            foundDevice = audioDevices.First();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot Find Perfered Audio Device Using " + audioDevices[0].Name + ex.Message);
        }
        return foundDevice;
    }
    ----->  if (Audiotext.Text == "Audio: ON")  <-----
    {

    }
```

It says the error is, 'Armored_Screen_Recorder.Form1.Audiotext' is a field but is used like a type.  Can you guys help me?

Comment: what is `Audiotext` here? where is it declared? also, very minor: but ... *field*

Comment: These lines: `EncoderDevice AudioDevices() {...}` looks like you copied and pasted a method from somewhere.

Comment: I see you use new feature called "local function". Are you sure you use C#7 (Visual Studio 2017)?

Answer (score 1):

> Looks like you've managed to copy/paste a method into another one.  I
>   think this is what you want:
>
> ```
> private void Audiotext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     Audiotext.Text = "Audio: ON";
>
>     if (Audiotext.Text == "Audio: ON")
>     {
>     }
> }
>
> EncoderDevice AudioDevices()
> {
>     EncoderDevice foundDevice = null;
>     Collection<EncoderDevice> audioDevices = EncoderDevices.FindDevices(EncoderDeviceType.Audio);
>     try
>     {
>         foundDevice = audioDevices.First();
>     }
>     catch (Exception ex)
>     {
>         MessageBox.Show("Cannot Find Perfered Audio Device Using " + audioDevices[0].Name + ex.Message);
>     }
>     return foundDevice;
> }
> ```

However, I'm not sure where you wanted to call AudioDevices from.  Put `AudioDevices()` there

Comment: Should probably add a call to `AudioDevices()`

Comment: Sometimes the error codes we get are descriptive, but not helpful.